# Using LZ4 with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, lz4

I am using the lz4-ruby gem.
However, it is incompatible with the c compressed lz4 file that is being posted to my application and cannot decompress the file.

https://code.google.com/p/lz4/

I need to decompress this file. Any ideas how I might best call a compatible lz4 decompression tool in my controller?

Comment: Is Ruby required to decode your data ?

Comment: Ideally yes @peter but the current ruby solution is incompatible with the standard lz4implementation. In the meantime, I have used fft to call a c library and this works.